# Ad CMS to an existing website

Tags: content-management-system

I am researching integrating CMS into an already existing website.

I would like to set up certain pages to be editable by co-workers where they can upload/edit content via an online form.

I am however, restricted in that I cannot use PHP(i know, lame!) and I don't have ftp access to this server. I edit the html files on a mirror site and they get uploaded to the webserver by my supervisor.

I would like to use a CMS similar to CushyCMS. Is there a cms service or code that I can put into my html files that would enable my co-workers to edit their pages?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

is not possible, you need to use a technology that support server side stuff like PHP, ASP, JSP, asp.net...

If you don't have direct access to the web site is impossible to do something like that.

An easy way was to install a normal CMS like joomla, wordpress, or many others and that designing the theme same as the existing one.